# Retrieve a string that was assigned into a random index inside of an array

Tags: java, arrays, random

So I need to locate where the "Nut" string is stored at. I thought my code would work just fine but obvious the ide just keep throwing me an error.

```
Random rd = new Random();
String[] hidingSpots = new String[100];
hidingSpots[rd.nextInt(hidingSpots.length)] = "Nut";
System.out.println("The nut has been hidden ...");
int nutLocation = 0;
while (nutLocation < hidingSpots.length) {
    if (hidingSpots[nutLocation].equals("Nut")) {
        System.out.println("Found it! It's in spot# " + hidingSpots[nutLocation]);
    }
    nutLocation++;
}
```

Comment: `the IDE just keeps throwing me an error` - it would be useful for us to know what that error was

Comment: Its an semantic error so there arent really any useful information . Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project HiddenNuts: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: that error has nothing to do with your code. It's a maven error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess, you're probably getting a `NullPointerException` because you only initialized one string within the `hidingSpots` array. When you first created the array of size 100, all the elements in the string array are null until you initialize them with something. Therefore, this line

```
if(hidingSpots[nutLocation].equals("Nut"))
```

is causing the error right now because 99 of the elements in `hidingSpots` are currently `null` and you can't compare a string to `null`.

Strings are objects, so their default values in arrays, like any other object, is going to be `null`. This is different than the default values of primitive types in arrays. For example, an `int` array of size 100 would contain 100 zeros by default.

Comment: Thanks, thats the problem!  instead of checking if its nut i just check if its not null.